# Values of dropdown overflows out of screen width

Tags: drop-down-menu, overflow, html-select

I have a dropdown generated using html select option. but it contains long description in it. On most of the browser the value overflow or not visible properly.  For more info I have created a demo on http://www.bootply.com/QYZwKn11Tq link. How to wrap text or is there any other alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

If the line is that long I wouldn't even wrap it, but just limit the width of dropdown. You could limit the width of the select and options like so

```
select, option { max-width: 200px; }
```

http://www.bootply.com/hNvXJLp4Ek

Comment: thanks for reply . take a look how i'm using bootstrap for it. <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
     <div class="input-group">
      <html:select property="abc" styleId="abx"
       styleClass="form-control" >
       <html:option value="">0000 All option 1</html:option>
       <c:if test="${requestScope.list != null}">
        <html:options collection="list" property="key"
         labelProperty="value" />
       </c:if>
      </html:select>
     </div>
    </div>                         Also I have to replicate same through out application so suggest general way. appreciated

Comment: It's a tricky issue then. I guess if you can't or won't adjust the styles you would have to go the route of truncating the option values (with javascript for instance)